# How to find the header of the Largest value of a specific row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need the column header of the largest value in a row.
I figured I could use Index Match with Max. It worked but I realized that the different spreadsheets are ranked differently.
So I need the column header for the largest value in a row for a specific row.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some sample data plus your expected outcome. Reading [ask] will help you to improve your question and us to help you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your input current result and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to find the column number, using `Index` and `Match`. It should not be too hard to find the header title, using `Range(1,Found_Column)`. (I suppose your header titles are on the first row?)

Comment: Since I can't show you the data, I will show something similar =INDEX($B$1:$F$1,0,MATCH(MAX($B2:$F2),$B2:$F2,0)), this is what I am using to return the header of the largest value. But now I need to return this for a specific row value. And this is spread across 2 spreadsheets.

Comment: @AbdullahShah You may not be able to show the actual data, BUT you CAN and SHOULD mock up data and expected output that represents the problem you are having.